# Spring Session Hazelcast Concurrency Control Multiple JVM on Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, hazelcast, spring-session

Product Versions:
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.0
com.hazelcast.hazelcast 5.0
spring-session-hazelcast 2.6.0
com.hazelcast.hazelcast-all - 4.2.2
spring-session-core 2.6.0
spring-boot-starter-security 2.6.0

Attempting to use Embedded Hazelcast cluster to support Session Replication and Session Concurrency Control across multiple JVM instances running on Tomcat.

I am trying to understand how to use the SpringSessionBackedSession registry class that supports concurrency across multiple JVM over the standard SessionRegistryImpl that does not.
Hazelcast Instance Creation:

```
@Bean(name = "hazelcastinstance")
    @SpringSessionHazelcastInstance
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        Config hazelcastConfiguration = new Config();

        hazelcastConfiguration.setClusterName("sp-cluster");
        hazelcastConfiguration.setInstanceName("hazelsessionstore");
        NetworkConfig hazelcastNetworkConfig = hazelcastConfiguration.getNetworkConfig();
        hazelcastNetworkConfig.setPort(hazelcastPort);

        JoinConfig hazelcastJoin = hazelcastNetworkConfig.getJoin();
        hazelcastJoin.getAutoDetectionConfig().setEnabled(false);
        hazelcastJoin.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);

        hazelcastJoin.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);

        // Add cluster members to allowable TCP IP instance from properties array
        for (String hazelMember : hazelcastMembers) {
            hazelcastJoin.getTcpIpConfig().addMember(hazelMember);
        }

        // Add this attribute to be able to query sessions by their
        // PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE's
        AttributeConfig attributeConfig = new AttributeConfig()
                .setName(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
                .setExtractorClassName(Hazelcast4PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

        // Configure the sessions map
        hazelcastConfiguration.getMapConfig(HAZEL_MAP).addAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
                .addIndexConfig(
                        new IndexConfig(IndexType.HASH, Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE))
                .setMaxIdleSeconds(serverSessionInactiveTimeout);

        SerializerConfig serializerConfig = new SerializerConfig();
        serializerConfig.setImplementation(new HazelcastSessionSerializer()).setTypeClass(MapSession.class);
        hazelcastConfiguration.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(serializerConfig);

        System.out.println("Multicast configuration is enabled: "
                + hazelcastConfiguration.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().isEnabled());
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfiguration);
    }
```

Hazelcast Session Repo Customizer

```
@Bean(name = "hazelcastrepo")
    public SessionRepositoryCustomizer<Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository> customize() {
        return (sessionRepository) -> {

            System.out.println("*******Session Repo Customizer Invoked");

            sessionRepository.setApplicationEventPublisher(this.applicationEventPublisher);
            sessionRepository.setFlushMode(FlushMode.IMMEDIATE);
            sessionRepository.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ON_SAVE);
            sessionRepository.setSaveMode(SaveMode.ALWAYS);
            sessionRepository.setSessionMapName(HAZEL_MAP);
            sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(serverSessionInactiveTimeout);
            setSessionRepository(sessionRepository);
        };
    }
```

Hazelcast Session Replication Setup

```
@DependsOn("hazelcastinstance")

    @Bean
    public com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter webFilter() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        
        properties.put("instance-name", "hazelsessionstore");
        properties.put("use-client", false);
        properties.put("sticky-session", "false");

        return new com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter(properties);
    }
```

Security Config applicable portion where I try to manually set the SessionRegistry to be an instance of SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry. *** This is where I get errors and tomcat fails to start with exception:

```
 
@Autowired private HazelcastHttpSessionConfig sessionConfig;

@Bean
SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry( sessionConfig.getSessionRepository());
}
  @Bean 
      public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
      
      return new HttpSessionEventPublisher(); }
     
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        try {
            
            httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable();
            
            
            httpSecurity.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            
            .maximumSessions(sessionConcurrentLimit)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(sessionPreventLogin)
            .expiredUrl("/user?multipleloginsdetected")
            .and()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .invalidSessionUrl("/user?expiredsession");
```

***Exceptions

```
2021-11-22 13:46:23.080  WARN 84700 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastHttpSessionConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\myuser\Documents\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\myapp\HazelcastHttpSessionConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.myapp.HazelcastHttpSessionConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ff667f1]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory has not been injected into @Configuration class
2021-11-22 13:46:23.112  INFO 84700 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-22 13:46:23.210 ERROR 84700 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastHttpSessionConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\myuser\Documents\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\myapp\HazelcastHttpSessionConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..myapp.HazelcastHttpSessionConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ff667f1]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory has not been injected into @Configuration class
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) [catalina.jar:9.0.55]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.55]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastHttpSessionConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\myuser\Documents\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\\myapp\HazelcastHttpSessionConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..myapp.HazelcastHttpSessionConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7ff667f1]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory has not been injected into @Configuration class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:191) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Any help is appreciated. Is one of the @Annotation methods from spring-session-hazelcast supposed to automatically replace the default SessionRegistry with a SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry instance? If so that does not seem to be happening in my case and the default SessionRegistry is what it is using. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was able to get this working by setting up the Hazelcast beans in the same class as my Security Config. Don't necessarily like how it didn't work with the HZ setups in a different class, but it probably was bean creation issues or Autowiring in the SessionRepository that was causing issue. For anyone struggling getting multiple JVM to do embedded Hazelcast session replication and session concurrency control here is my working solution running on two Tomcat 9 instances:

```
package com.myapp;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.session.FlushMode;
import org.springframework.session.MapSession;
import org.springframework.session.SaveMode;
import org.springframework.session.Session;
import org.springframework.session.config.SessionRepositoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.session.hazelcast.Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository;
import org.springframework.session.hazelcast.Hazelcast4PrincipalNameExtractor;
import org.springframework.session.hazelcast.HazelcastSessionSerializer;
import org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.SpringSessionHazelcastInstance;
import org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.EnableHazelcastHttpSession;
import org.springframework.session.security.SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry;

import com.hazelcast.config.AttributeConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.config.IndexConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.IndexType;
import com.hazelcast.config.JoinConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.NetworkConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.SerializerConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;

import com.myapp.service.authentication.LoginFailureHandlerService;
import com.myapp.service.authentication.LoginSuccessHandlerService;
import com.myapp.service.eventlisteners.CustomAccessDeniedHandler;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableHazelcastHttpSession
public class SecurityConfig<S extends Session> extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    

    @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
    private String ldapBaseDn;

    @Value("${ldap.admin.dn}")
    private String ldapSecurityPrincipal;

    @Value("${ldap.admin.password}")
    private String ldapPrincipalPassword;

    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${username.search.password}")
    private String ldapUserPassword;

    @Value("${username.search.pattern}")
    private String ldapUserSearchPattern;

    @Value("${myapp.cookiename}")
    private String myappCookieName;
    
    @Value("${session.concurrentlimit}")
    private Integer sessionConcurrentLimit;
    
    @Value("${session.preventlogin}")
    private Boolean sessionPreventLogin;

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("" + SecurityConfig.class);
    

    
    @Bean 
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
      
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher(); 
        
    }
        
     
    @Bean
    public LoginSuccessHandlerService ldaploginsuccesshandler() {

        return new LoginSuccessHandlerService();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler ldaploginfailurehandler() {

        return new LoginFailureHandlerService();
    }



    private String HAZEL_MAP = "HAZEL_MAP";

    @Value("${server.servlet.session.timeout}")
    private Integer serverSessionInactiveTimeout;

    @Value("${hazelcast.members}")
    private String[] hazelcastMembers;

    @Value("${hazelcast.port}")
    private Integer hazelcastPort;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
    
    private Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository;
    
    @Bean(name = "hazelcastrepo")
    public SessionRepositoryCustomizer<Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository> customize() {
        return (sessionRepository) -> {

            sessionRepository.setApplicationEventPublisher(this.applicationEventPublisher);
            sessionRepository.setFlushMode(FlushMode.IMMEDIATE);
            sessionRepository.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ON_SAVE);
            sessionRepository.setSaveMode(SaveMode.ALWAYS);
            sessionRepository.setSessionMapName(HAZEL_MAP);
            sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(serverSessionInactiveTimeout);
            setSessionRepository(sessionRepository);
            
        };
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "hazelcastinstance")
    @SpringSessionHazelcastInstance
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        
        Config hazelcastConfiguration = new Config();

        hazelcastConfiguration.setClusterName("myapp-cluster");
        hazelcastConfiguration.setInstanceName("hazelsessionstore");
        NetworkConfig hazelcastNetworkConfig = hazelcastConfiguration.getNetworkConfig();
        hazelcastNetworkConfig.setPort(hazelcastPort);

        JoinConfig hazelcastJoin = hazelcastNetworkConfig.getJoin();
        hazelcastJoin.getAutoDetectionConfig().setEnabled(false);
        hazelcastJoin.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);

        hazelcastJoin.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);

        // Add cluster members to allowable TCP IP instance from properties array
        for (String hazelMember : hazelcastMembers) {
            hazelcastJoin.getTcpIpConfig().addMember(hazelMember);
        }

        // Add this attribute to be able to query sessions by their
        // PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE's
        AttributeConfig attributeConfig = new AttributeConfig()
                .setName(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
                .setExtractorClassName(Hazelcast4PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

        // Configure the sessions map
        hazelcastConfiguration.getMapConfig(HAZEL_MAP).addAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
                .addIndexConfig(
                        new IndexConfig(IndexType.HASH, Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE))
                .setMaxIdleSeconds(serverSessionInactiveTimeout);

        // Use custom serializer to de/serialize sessions faster. This is optional.
        // Note that, all members in a cluster and connected clients need to use the
        // same serializer for sessions. For instance, clients cannot use this
        // serializer // where members are not configured to do so.

        SerializerConfig serializerConfig = new SerializerConfig();
        serializerConfig.setImplementation(new HazelcastSessionSerializer()).setTypeClass(MapSession.class);
        hazelcastConfiguration.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(serializerConfig);

        
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfiguration);
    }
    
    @DependsOn("hazelcastinstance")
    @Bean
    public com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter webFilter() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Set<HazelcastInstance> hzSet = com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.getAllHazelcastInstances();
        hzSet.forEach(set -> {
            System.out.println("Hazel Instance Name: " + set.getName());

        });

        properties.put("instance-name", "hazelsessionstore");
        properties.put("use-client", false);
        properties.put("sticky-session", "false");

        return new com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter(properties);
    }



    @DependsOn("hazelcastinstance")
    @Bean
        SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
            return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(getSessionRepository() );
    }

     
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        try {
            
            httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable();
            
            
            httpSecurity.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            
            .maximumSessions(sessionConcurrentLimit)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(sessionPreventLogin)
            .expiredUrl("/user?multipleloginsdetected")
            .and()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .invalidSessionUrl("/user?expiredsession");
                
            
            
           httpSecurity
                *** NON RELEVANT SECURITY REDACTED***

            


    }
    
    

    public Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository getSessionRepository() {
        return sessionRepository;
    }


    public void setSessionRepository(Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository) {
        this.sessionRepository = sessionRepository;
    }

}
```